# Debug in Django (show what's happening in the background)

Tags: python, django, debugging

Is there a way to properly debug in django. I mean to show everything not only when something doesn't work right. For now my console (Powershell with manage.py runserver) only shows me the urls (pages) where I am.

Here is an example:

[image]

Can I show whats happening in the background.

I.e. I submit a password reset. The console only shows how the next page is called and not what it actually did.

I tried django_debug_toolbar, but I am not sure if its something I need.

Comment: You probably want to use a custom logger for that.  Maybe decorate the view and log what you need manually.  But what exactly you want to see, what do you think is really missing here?

Comment: You can use the python debugger. `pdb.set_trace()` with runserver. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace

Or install `ipdb`, which gives you extra ipython features such as code highlighting and tab completion.
https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb

Comment: If you want to see what's going on without pausing at breakpoints and stepping through, you should use the built-in logging features. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/

Comment: How does the pdb.set_trace() work? Where do I have to put it in?

Comment: @wm3ndez My project is a LDAP user authentication. And I try to edit attributes directly in the LDAP. At this moment I can't check if it does anything in the LDAP or not. Thats why I need a good debugger.

Comment: Put `set_trace()` In your source code. It will pause execution at that line and let you debug. It's a python version of the  original Gnu Project Debugger, so the interface might be a bit old fashioned. If you are using a full featured IDE, there might be a built-in debugger there, if you prefer more visual tools.

Comment: @ZeraICT have you tested ipdb? with ipdb you can add breakpoints in differents parts of your code and inspect just at this point. You can add a breakpoint adding `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` and the server will be stop until you end your inspection

Comment: start with `print` statements in your code -- but I haven't used Powershell so I can't be sure that the output will get there.  Then be vigilant about removing them before you commit.

Comment: @ZeraICT as suggested above, pdb or ipdb is a very powerful tool.  You should try it out.

Comment: why don't you use django debug toolbar